# How to prove that a monotone function is differentiable at some point?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory

This fact, which eventually belongs to Lebesgue, is usually proved with some measure theory (and we prove that the function is differentiable a.e.). Is there a significantly different approach? Let me explain how it could look like. Say, if the function is convex, we may touch its graph by a Euclidean disc (lying in the épigraphe), and in the point of touch there exists a derivative.

Maybe, it allows to prove something about the set of points where there is no derivative, not only that it has Lebesgue measure $0$. Or is this impossible and for any set $A$ of Lebesgue measure $0$ there exists a monotone function $f$ not differentiable at any point $a\in A$?

UPD: according to a comment by Bill Johnson, this statement is true, even for a Lipschitz function.

Comment: There is a big literature on universal differentiability sets on spaces of dimension larger than one that have Lebesgue measure zero. On the line everything is known (a measurable subset of the line contains a point of differentiability of every Lipschitz function iff it has positive measure). The most recent paper on this topic with which I am familiar is Doré, Michael; Maleva, Olga A compact universal differentiability set with Hausdorff dimension one. Israel J. Math. 191 (2012), no. 2, 889–900.

Comment: A direct proof of Lebesgue's theorem, as well as the example requested in the last sentence, is given on pages 6-9 of the classic text Functional Analysis, by Riesz-Nagy, well before the discussion of integration or measure theory.

Comment: @roysmith thank you for the reference. Actually, I see two significantly different approaches: using Rising Sun Lemma (as in Riesz-Nagy) and using some covering theorem like Vitali theorem. In a board sense, they both use greedy choice of intervals, but somehow differently. And of course both they proof that function is differentiable in some point by proving that a.e. point works. While I wonder whether there is another way to find such a point. 

Well, I still have not seen Botsko's note mentioned in the answer by Igor Rivin.

Comment: Note that a.e. differentiability of monotone and of Lipschitz functions are strictly related. Indeed, if you rotate the graph of an increasing function 45 degrees you get  a graph of  a 1-Lipschitz function, and conversely.

Comment: @Pietro this is nice observation, but, say, points of a jump for $f$ produce points of locally linear function for the rotated function.

Comment: I find your update confusing. How does Bill's (interesting) comment address the question of whether any $A$ of measure zero is the set of non-differentiability of some increasing $f$? (It seems clear in fact that not all $A$'s are possible because these sets must have certain topological properties.)

Comment: "a measurable subset of the line contains a point of differentiability of every Lipschitz function iff it has positive measure", i.e. for any set $A$ of measure 0 there exist a monotone function not differentiable at any point of $A$. Am I correct?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Yes, what it says is that if $|A|=0$, then there is a Lipschitz $f$ such that $A$ is *contained* in the set (but not necessarily equal to) where $f'$ doesn't exist, but that doesn't answer the question of what $A$'s exactly are possible as exceptional sets.

Comment: The answer to this question is: Exactly the $G_{\delta\sigma}$ sets of measure zero are exceptional sets (for Lipschitz, but I'm hoping the answer is the same for increasing, without having really thought about it). See here: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1242738925

Comment: I was probably unclear, I was thinking how to describe subsets of exceptional sets.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: That of course also immediately follows from the more complete result I quoted since any null set is contained in a $G_{\delta}$ null set by regularity.

Comment: @yes, and the easy construction is presented in Riesz-Nagy: cover your set $A$ of measure 0 by a system of intervals $\Delta_i$ with finite sum of lengths such that each point is covered infinitely often, then define $f(x)=\int_\infty^x \sum \chi_{\Delta_i}(t) dt$. This function has infinite derivative at each point from $A$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: yes, the jumps in the graph of the monotone function  at discontinuities  are intended to be filled with a segment, before rotating (so the  corresponding Lipschitz function will be locally linear with derivative $\pm 1$ there). btw this operation has also been considered from monotone vector valued maps to $1$-Lipschitz maps.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there are a couple of alternate proofs: Here is one:

An Elementary Proof of Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem
Michael W. Botsko
The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 110, No. 9 (Nov., 2003), pp. 834

And this proof by Faure (from the Real Analysis exchange, 2003), which uses Riesz's 1932 idea: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1149698560